# Problems with IR2011 high-side switch

Tags: mosfet-driver

I have made a board with an IR2011 to do both high-side and low-side switching. The low side switch works fine. The MOSFET is a BSC0702LS.

But with the high-side switch, if I don't attach the load, there is output of 5 V from either HO or Vs even when HIN is off. If I attach a solenoid or motor, it works OK. If I attach a device, it doesn't work (source voltage is only 2 V, drain voltage is 24 V, I'm testing with 24 instead of 48 V).
I have made a design as follows:

[image: schematic]

Here is the typical connection diagram from the datasheet:

[image: typical connection diagram from datasheet]

Comment: Your description is not very clear.  If no load, top MOSFET Source/Drain is floating, Gate has no reference, ...

Comment: Please draw MOSFETs symbolically.

Comment: Try connecting a 10k resistor between HO & COM/GND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These chips generate the high side bias through the bootstrap diode (D2 in your diagram) and some capacitor (C13 in your diagram). When the low side FET turns on, current from VCC (your +12V) flows through the diode into the cap and charges the cap to 12V. When the bottom FET then opens, the "bottom" of the capacitor moves up with the VDS of the bottom FET and is now 12V above your switch node (CH1_PRECHARGER).

The low side FET needs to be switching fairly frequently to keep C13 charged. If you are approaching 100% duty cycle, or your switching frequency is too low, the cap will empty and there will be nothing holding the top FET on anymore. With 100nF of cap, I wouldn't expect this to stay on for very long. These chips are used for SMPS half bridges which are switching at fairly high speeds.

If your application requires long ON times for the high side FET, or you don't want to have to worry about it, you can used an isolated DC/DC regulator and attach the output V- to HS and the positive to VB.

Comment: Thanks Stiddily. i didn't know that's how high side driver works. i guess i would have to switch to either using P Channel Mosfet or isolated DC/DC to charge the capacitor.

Comment: Yes should have been, when the bottom FET opens. I will correct that, thank you.